# How can I get a screenshot on a Dell 2-in-1?

Tags: windows-10, screenshot

How can I get a screenshot on a [Dell 2-in-1](http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/2-in-1-laptops/sc/2-in-1-laptop) combination laptop and tablet? The on-screen keyboard doesn't seem to allow it.

Comment: Use the built-in tool or printscrn.

Answer (score 1):

Windows provides built-in screenshot capabilities with the <kbd>PrintScrn</kbd> key. Different combinations of this key, the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, and <kbd>Alt</kbd> key yield different results. [See here](http://quickfics.facultyinnovate.utexas.edu/8-ways-to-apture-screenshots-on-a-pc/) for a list of options for your computer.

As per the above linked article, if you're using Windows 10, and don't have the <kbd>PrintScrn</kbd> key on your keyboard, you can use the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> combination.